# unix Command doesn't work

Tags: unix, shell

The command:

```
tar c DIR | compress >DIR.tar.Z
```

which works on a Debian-based Linux, fails on SunOS.

Why?

Comment: What is the default place for the output on SunOs? It it to tape or to stdout?

Comment: When asking about a command that failed, you need to explain exactly how it failed. Was there an error message? What was it? Was an empty file created? A file with the wrong data? Did your computer explode? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Answer (score 5):

Traditionally, `tar` tries to write to a tape device (/dev/rmt0 or such) if an output file isn't specified.

Default-stdout is a GNU tar change, but SunOS is not Linux and usually does not use GNU userspace; it's a bit more… traditional. Thus you need `tar cf - DIR` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `compress` command is not installed on the SunOS System.

I used the following command to zip files from SunOS:

```
tar cf - | gzip >myzip.zip
```

Because, systems may both be unixoid but linux is not SunOS is not HP-UX - although all have tar commands.